Connection Closed when Testing Repository using Testcontainers with JDBC Template
I am trying to test the below UserRepositoryImpl class that inserts a User into a MySql database.
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    private final JdbcTemplate template;

    public UserRepositoryImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer insert(User user) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO EXPENSE_TRACKER.USERS (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        return template.update(sql, user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getEmail());
    }
}

I need to test this method and for this reason, I have created the next simple test that uses Testcontainers.
@SpringBootTest
class UserRepositoryImplSpec extends TestContainersSpec {

    @Subject
    UserRepositoryImpl repository

    def setup() {
        repository = new UserRepositoryImpl(dataSource)
    }

    def "Successfully insert a new user in the database"() {
        given: "a user"
        def user = new User(username: 'testUser', password: 'myPassword', firstName: 'myName',
                lastName: 'myLastName', email: 'my.email@hotmail.com')

        when: "calling the insert method"
        def result = repository.insert(user)

        then: "the user is saved"
        def dbUser = sql.firstRow("SELECT * FROM EXPENSE_TRACKER.USERS WHERE USERNAME = ?", [user.username])
        assert dbUser != null
        assert dbUser.get('ID') == result
        assert dbUser.get('USERNAME') == user.username
        assert dbUser.get('PASSWORD') == user.password
        assert dbUser.get('FIRSTNAME') == user.firstName
        assert dbUser.get('LASTNAME') == user.lastName
        assert dbUser.get('EMAIL') == user.email
    }
}

The TestContainersSpec class besides the container itself utilizes the creation of a reusable network so that I can use the same container. I needed to find a way to configure my Datasource and I thought to mock it based on the Sql instance shown below. Since this is an integration test, I know that this is not the way to go (mocking), but I will see on how to change this later on.
class TestContainersSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    public static MySQLContainer mySQL

    public static Network network = createReusableNetwork('expense-network')

    @Shared
    Sql sql

    @Shared
    DataSource dataSource

    def setup() {
        mySQL = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0.28")
                .withExposedPorts(3306)
                .withDatabaseName('EXPENSE_TRACKER')
                .withUsername('root')
                .withPassword('test')
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withReuse(true)
                .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3))
                .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(LoggerFactory.getLogger("mySQL")))
        mySQL.start()

        dataSource = Mock()
        sql = Sql.newInstance(mySQL.jdbcUrl, mySQL.username, mySQL.password, mySQL.driverClassName)
        dataSource.connection >> sql.connection
        createLocalDb(sql)
    }

    def createLocalDb(Sql sql) {
        ['cleanup.sql', 'schema.sql'].collect{ path ->
            getClass().getResource("/$path").text.trim()
        }.each { queries ->
            queries.tokenize(";").each{
                try {
                    sql.execute(it)
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    println e.message
                }
            }
        }
        println 'Local database ready'
    }

    static Network createReusableNetwork(String name) {
        String id = DockerClientFactory.instance().client().listNetworksCmd().exec().stream()
                .filter(network -> network.getName().equals(name)
                        && network.getLabels() == DockerClientFactory.DEFAULT_LABELS)
                .map(com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Network::getId)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseGet(() -> DockerClientFactory.instance().client().createNetworkCmd()
                        .withName(name)
                        .withOptions(['mtu': '1350'])
                        .withCheckDuplicate(true)
                        .withLabels(DockerClientFactory.DEFAULT_LABELS)
                        .exec().getId())

        return new Network() {
            @Override
            String getId() {
                return id
            }

            @Override
            void close() {
            }

            @Override
            Statement apply(@NotNull Statement statement, @NotNull Description description) {
                return statement
            }
        }
    }
}

However, when I execute my test, I am getting the next error:
May 19, 2024 2:22:04 PM groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand execute
WARNING: Failed to execute: SELECT * FROM EXPENSE_TRACKER.USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? because: No operations allowed after connection closed.
May 19, 2024 2:22:04 PM groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand execute
WARNING: Failed to execute: SELECT * FROM EXPENSE_TRACKER.USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? because: No operations allowed after connection closed.

No operations allowed after connection closed.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:111)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:74)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1610)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$CreatePreparedStatementCommand.execute(Sql.java:4808)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$CreatePreparedStatementCommand.execute(Sql.java:4786)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.getAbstractStatement(Sql.java:4625)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.getPreparedStatement(Sql.java:4640)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.getPreparedStatement(Sql.java:4729)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.access$1000(Sql.java:234)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$PreparedQueryCommand.runQuery(Sql.java:4925)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand.execute(Sql.java:4856)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:2050)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1980)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1824)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.firstRow(Sql.java:2295)
    at com.expense.tracker.repository.UserRepositoryImplSpec.Successfully insert a new user in the database(UserRepositoryImplSpec.groovy:27)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ConnectionIsClosedException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:104)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.checkClosed(NativeSession.java:756)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:556)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1539)

I can't see the reason, my connection closes. Can you propose me a solution?

sql gets closed after db initialization, then repository is used to insert, and then sql used again to read db...id try using repository to read back the user, or if that doesnt work, create another repository with same data source to read back the user

I always recommend to use Testcontainer's JDBC support when trying to test with a real database in spring-boot. Just define jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0.36:///databasename as datasource url.
You can also let it execute an init-script jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0.36:///databasename?TC_INITSCRIPT=somepath/init_mysql.sql
